Export metrics from Openshift Thanos to Mimir
I'd like to export live the metrics collected by Openshift and stored in Thanos to Mimir.
I've installed Mimir in my personal Openshift Namepsace
I've also installed grafana-agent hoping that I can use it to export live the metrics from Thanos and remote-write to Mimir.
This is my current configuration of the grafana-agent:
metrics:
      wal_directory: /tmp/grafana-agent/wal

configs:
  - name: agent
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: agent
      scrape_interval: 10s
      static_configs:                    
        - targets: ["mythanos-service"]
      remote_write:
        - url: http://mimir-nginx.sandbox-dev.svc.cluster.local/api/v1/push

The problem is that in this way I am scraping the Thanos metrics (e.g. thanos_query_concurrent..) and not the metrics stored in Prometheus (like POD cpu, memory, and so on).
How can I configure the grafana-agent to export the metrics out of Openshift thanos? If grafana-agent is not the right tool what is it?
As followup question, I'd like to export only a subset of metrics (e.g all the metrics where the namespace label is "mynamespace"
PS: I do not have cluster permission in Openshift.
